# Європа чи Европа?

Tags: власні-назви, from-greek

На телебаченні можна почути "Европа", замість звичного "Європа". Особисто мені це здається дивним. Можливо, я помиляюсь, і правильно говорити "Европа"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
У нас заохочуються запитання, які  демонструють **спробу автора самостійно відповісти** на нього. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть [edit] у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: [Podïbna problematika](/a/2629/585): _ewrika_, _newroloqiä_, _newron_…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тільки один варіант **Європа** подають різні словники, зокрема і [Словарь української мови за ред. Бориса Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D1%94%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0), і [Словник-довідник Віталія Жайворонка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury/%D1%94%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0).

Чинний [Український правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par91) подає так:

> 2. Коли іншомовне **е** (іноді дифтонг аі) на початку слова **вимовляється** в українській мові як звукосполучення **й + е**, воно передається літерою ***є***:
>
>    *європеєць, європейський, єгер, єнот, єресь; Ємен, Євпаторія, Євразія, **Європа**, Євфрат, Єгипет.*

Використання слова **Европа** пояснюється лише змінами правопису 1929 р. на інші (1999 р. + чинний правопис), що відбулися за політичних міркувань. Ірина Фаріон у книзі [„Правопис — корсет мови“](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Farion_Iryna/Pravopys_-_korset_movy7.pdf#page=49) подає гарну таблицю, де чітко розмежовуються правила цих правописів. *Ймовірно, ЗМІ, телебачення, навіть деякі науковці та інші використовують у своїй лексиці саме такі слова і правила, оскільки є прибічниками правопису 1929 р.*

Однак з точки зору ЧИННОГО правопису пишемо тільки **Європа**.

Comment: Але ж запитання було не про чинний правопис, а про те як правильно. Також не розумію чому в українській мові на початку **вропа* має звучати саме *й+е*.

Comment: @Yola *право*пис і є як *прав*ильно. Наскільки це виправдано - вже інше питання. Скоріше за все, причина у часі і посереднику запозичення.
В результаті грецьке εὖ передається і як ев-, і як є-: евфемізм, евтаназія, але Євфрат, Євангеліє, Європа. При чому, останні, очевидно, запозичені значно давніше.

Comment: @xpoback якби правопис - це було правильно, то навіщо їх змінюють час від часу. Може вже настав час і це змінити? Я не за і не проти цих змін.

Answer (score 0):

Інша думка. Європа з російського, бо в російське "E" читається "Є". Див. також:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcHAqEx5JV0